# How to input the value from UI button in Teble View cell to the variable declared in Table View Controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib, indexpath

I want to save the value of filled button(●) into the array "q.answer[indexPath.row]" about each question "q.question[indexPath.row]).
currentQuizButtonIndex is currently renewed every time when ◯ changes to ● by tapping. However, I have no idea how to save in to variable q which is declared in TableViewController.
[View Controller display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDabO.png)

**Code about QuizCell.swift (TableCell which is about 5 buttons and UIlabel.)**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol QuizCellDelegate {
    func quizCellDidChangeCurrentButtonIndex(_ cell: QuizCell, index: Int)
}

class QuizCell: UITableViewCell {
    var currentQuizButtonIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            let value = self.currentQuizButtonIndex
            self.updateCurrentQuizButton(value)
            if let delegate = self.delegate {
                delegate.quizCellDidChangeCurrentButtonIndex(self, index: value)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var answerButtons: [UIButton]!
var delegate: QuizCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //print("ここまできてるか確認")
    // Initialization code
}

@IBAction func didTapQuizButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let index = self.answerButtons.firstIndex(of: sender){
        self.currentQuizButtonIndex = index
        delegate?.quizCellDidChangeCurrentButtonIndex(self, index: index)
        print(index)
    }
}

private func updateCurrentQuizButton(_ currentIndex: Int){
    for (index, answerButton) in self.answerButtons.enumerated(){
        if index == currentIndex {
            answerButton.setTitle("●", for: .normal)
        } else {
            answerButton.setTitle("○", for: .normal)

        }
    }
}


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

**Code about View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class AnswerQuizViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {


var q: QuestionSeries!

@IBOutlet weak var quizTableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   quizTableView.dataSource = self
    quizTableView.delegate = self

    // cell xibファイルを使うときは書く必要があるやつ。
//        quizTableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.Cells.QuizCellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.Cells.QuizCellIdentifier)
        quizTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuizCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "QuizCellIdentifier")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
//    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
//        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
////        if segue.identifier == K.Segue.checkResult {
////            let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
////            answerQuizViewController.q =
////            print(answerQuizViewController.q)
//    }


}

// MARK: - quizTableViewのアレンジ

extension AnswerQuizViewController: UITableViewDataSource, QuizCellDelegate {
    func quizCellDidChangeCurrentButtonIndex(_ cell: QuizCell, index: Int) {
        if let indexPath = self.quizTableView.indexPath(for: cell){
            self.q.question[indexPath.row].answer = index
            print(index)
        }else{
            print("ここきてます")
        }
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return q.question.count
    //print(q.question.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let question = q.question[indexPath.row]
    let cell = quizTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.Cells.QuizCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! QuizCell
    cell.questionLabel.text = question.text
   // print(question.text)
return cell
}
}
```

It is also helpful if you have any idea of implementing this by alternative way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you create a static array and store your data into that array.
when the button is tapped you can append it into that static array.

Create a new file. Just a basic "Swift file".

```
struct structName {
    static var qArray: [String] = []
}
```

Then append data by:

```
structName.q.append()
```

Finally get your data trough:

```
structName.q[index]
```

Comment: If you got any questions feel free to ask me!

Comment: I really appreciate your kind comment! Now I understand how to use static array. And I am sorry, I realized I wrote misleading sentence. `index` has the value 1~5 which I would like to save, and `indexPath.row` has the question number. So, I would like to get my data through `structName.q[indexPath.row]`, in which index of each question is saved. **Is it possible to add the value without using append()?**  When selected button is changed, it should be saved at corresponding indexPath.row (question number).

Comment: Have you tried using didSelectRowAt? If not i can give you a quick example. With didSelectRowAt we can give the indexpath.row to a static variable. That way you can check what row is pressed let me know beacuse then i will edit my answer and show you.

Comment: Using static properties in this way to avoid having to design a proper app architecture is not good practice.  You'd be better considering the delegate pattern to allow the tableView cell to pass information back to the VC.

Comment: @flanker do you got a example?

Comment: Numerous tutorials and examples around if you search.  If I get time I'll add an answer later.

Comment: @Bear Thank you very much for your comments. I tried using didSelectRowAt, and by adding delegate method, array element was changed as I wanted.

Comment: @flanker, Bear Thank you very much for your comments. I am sorry for late for reply.

Comment: @tasmicsy if the answer worked please accept the answer with the checkmark :D glad i could help a bit!